# Relation between degenerate elliptic operators and elliptic operators

Tags: partial-differential-equations, elliptic-operators

A differential operator of second order $f=f(\cdot,u,Du,D^2u):\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}\to \mathbb{R}$ is said to be degenerate elliptic, if

$\forall A\leq B \,\,\text{in}\,\,\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}\,\,\,\,$ $\Longrightarrow$ $\,\,\,\,f(a,b,c,B) \leq f(a,b,c,A)\,\,\,\,$ for all $(a,b,c)\in\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^n$

holds. With $A\leq B\,\,\text{in}\,\,\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ we mean that $B-A$ is positive semidefinite.

How does this compare to usual (uniformly) elliptic differential operators? Is it a weaker concept? I can't really see how they relate...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you state your definition of elliptic operator and compare the difference?

Comment: Where did you read this definition?

Comment: @Arctic Char Hi and thanks to both of you for your answers. I know (uniformly) elliptic operators in the same way as they are defined in: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_operator But I just can't see how these two concepts relate?

Comment: @quarague This definition is given in pretty much every book on viscosity solutions, e.g. in User's guide to viscosity solutions of second order partial differential equations from Crandall...

Comment: If $f$ is linear, you can assume $B=0$ in the condition and then $-A$ is positive semidefinite should correspond to the ellipticity condition on wikipedia.

Comment: Unfortunately I still can't see who they correspond. Especially what the positive semidefiniteness of $-A$ helps me? I'm so sorry, could you please explain your thinking? Thanks!